# SQL update table using select from and multiple joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join, phpmyadmin, sql-update

Here are the relevant columns of my tables

- `bia_panels` ( `id, sign_id, value,  project_id` )
- `bia_clients` ( `id, name` )
- `bia_projects` ( `id, name, client_id, city_id` )
- `bia_cities` ( `id, name` )

I am attempting to update the `bia_panels.project_id` to the `bia_projects.id` where the  `bia_panels.value = bia_clients.name` and the `panels.project_id =000` and the value is not blank of course I must use multiple joins to get there

```
    -- UPDATE
SELECT * FROM
`bia_panels` AS t1
    JOIN  bia_clients AS t2 
        ON t1.value = t2.name 
    JOIN bia_projects AS  t3 
        ON t2.id = t3.client_id 


-- SET t1.project_id = t3.id

-- WHERE t1.value<>'' AND t1.project_id = '000' 
WHERE t1.value <>''
```

The problem is that this is not giving me the correct results (my project ids are not correct somewhere in the joins multiple results are returned so they break

I know that once I am able to get the select portion correct I can use an update

For example there may be multiple panels where the `value=client.name` but not all of them are the same project ID

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Answer (score 0):

> and bia_panels.ID = bia_panels.project_id

join condition is missing in your select query, this should be added like

```
 JOIN bia_projects ON bia_clients.id = bia_projects.client_id  and bia_panels.ID = bia_panels.project_id
```

following query should give right output

```
SELECT  sign_id, value, left(sign_id, 3) AS city_ID  ,  
bia_clients.id AS 'client id',  bia_projects.id AS proj_id , bia_cities.id
FROM bia_panels
 JOIN  bia_clients ON bia_panels.value = bia_clients.name 
 JOIN bia_projects ON bia_clients.id = bia_projects.client_id  and bia_panels.ID = bia_panels.project_id
JOIN bia_cities ON bia_projects.city_id = bia_cities.id WHERE bia_panels.value<>'' AND bia_panels.project_id = '000' ORDER BY value
```

Answer (score 0):

I would little bit reorganize your query into UPDATE query:

```
UPDATE bia_panels p, bia_clients c, bia_projects t
  SET p.project_id=t.id
  WHERE p.value=c.name
    AND t.client_id=c.id
    AND p.project_id=''
```